# Cannot find module '@testing-library/dom' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js' Require stack:

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, user-event

In a project we recently started using userEvent instead of fireEvent but now we are getting this issue

```
FAIL src/modules/DashboardHeader/index.test.tsx     

      ● Test suite failed to run  

        Cannot find module '@testing-library/dom' from 'node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js'  

        Require stack:  

          node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js  

          node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/index.js  

          src/modules/DashboardHeader/index.test.tsx  

           5 | 
           6 | 
        >  7 | import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
```

Answer (score 6):

As per the documentation
https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

in order to use userEvent, we need not just "@testing-library/user-event" but also @testing-library/dom.

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event @testing-library/dom
```

So when I checked there was no entry for @testing-library/dom . After installing it, it started working.